# Modify object properties conditionally with jq

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

I have this sample of JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "val1",
        "expire": { "$value": 10 }
    },
    {
        "name": "val2",
        "expire": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "val3"
    }
]
```

And I want to transform it to this form with jq:

```
[
    {
        "name": "val1",
        "expire": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "val2",
        "expire": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "val3",
        "expire": null
    }
]
```

All that I've found it's if-then-else, but it looks like I have no clue how to build right expression.

Condition based on type check, it looks like a right way, but just return "compile"-time error, I don't know how to fix it:

```
.[] | { name, expire: (if .expire then (if type(.expire) == "number" then .expire else .expire."$value" end) else null end) }
```

Condition based on `"$value"` check, somehow filter out second object:

```
.[] | { name, expire: (if .expire then (if .expire."$value"? then .expire."$value" else .expire end) else null end) }
```

As I understand, the problem here in internal if, where second object checked with `.expire."$value"?`, error was thrown and object removed from result because of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this filter:

```
map( {name, 
      "expire": (.expire | if type == "object" then .["$value"] elif type == "number" then . else null end) } )
```

or (with significantly different semantics in edge cases):

```
map(.expire |= if type == "object" then .["$value"]
               elif type == "number" then . else null end)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can think of it another way as updating each object's `expire` property with the `"$value"` if present, or the current value.  If the value doesn't exist, it's just simply `null`.

```
.[].expire |= (."$value"? // .)
```